# Java iteration project issue

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iteration

I need to do this for homework, and I cant seem to get it to work... What it is suposed to do is output this:

```
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Here is my code:

```
public class stars {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        for(int l = 1; l<= 10; l++){
            System.out.println();
            for(int i = 10; i>= 1; i--){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This seems to output this:

```
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

I was hoping someone could help me! Thanks!

Comment: Have the inner loop start at `l+1` and run it to `i <= 10` (and increment `i`)

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int l = 1; l<= 10; l++){
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 10; i>= 1; i--){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```

You need to change the terminating condition of `inner loop` from `i >= 1` to `i >= l`, else it will run `10 times` for every iteration.

```
for(int l = 1; l<= 10; l++){
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 10; i>= l; i--){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```

And please, don't name variables with the name like : - `l` seems like `One`, similarly, `O` seems like `Zero`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment above:

```
for(int l = 1; l<= 10; l++){
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = l + 1; i <= 10; i++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```